# Linux cannot recognise my RAID0 array drives

Tags: debian, amd, asus, raid0

**OS:**
64bit Debian 11 Bullseye with KDE Plasma Desktop environment
**PC Specs:**
AMD FX-4300 Quad Core Processor,
nVidia Geforce GTX 970 Graphics card,
ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0 Motherboard,
16GB unknown brand DDR2 RAM
**Problem:**
My RAID0 array was created in bios; and Windows can recognise it but Linux can't.
How do I get Linux to recognise it?

Comment: Don't you see any drives in Debian?

Comment: "fake"-raid (like that provided by motherboards and many cheap "raid" cards - called "fake" because it's just software raid pretending to be hardware, and generally doing a bad job of it) is generally handled by [dmraid](http://people.redhat.com/~heinzm/sw/dmraid/), so you need to have that package installed on your Debian system.  grub also needs to be configured to boot debian from your dmraid partition.    BTW, do you need to dual boot windows on this machine?  If not, you'd be better off making a backup of any windows data you need to keep and rebuilding it using linux mdadm raid.

Comment: Also BTW, RAID-0 is garbage. It's like actively begging the universe to destroy your data on a whim.  Don't use it unless you don't care **at all** about your data. If you think you need to use it for more capacity or for speed, then you almost certainly don't.  Buy a bigger, faster drive instead (maybe an SSD. they've got big, cheap, and fast since your M5A97 board was made - I have one of them, with an FX-8320). RAID-0's only semi-valid use is for a temporary scratch fs for transient data that doesn't matter because it can be easily downloaded or created from other data on reliable storage.